# Azure Point to Site VPN Windows 10

Tags: azure

Hi we are using Azure Point to site VPN  and with Windows 10 we cannot access any shares . We can ping by IP and name and can RDP to servers  but when accessing shares it says user name cannot be found. I have went into RASPhone file under %appdata%\Microsoft\Network\Connectioms\pbk and edited the file to have UseRASCredentials with value of 0 but it keeps reverting back.
Reason for doing that was that in Windows 10 every time i connect to Azure VPN it creates entries in credentials manager with *session which has no username and thus it tries to use this. 
No issues with Windows 7 as it does not create these entries. Anyone else seen this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Reason for doing that was that in Windows 10 every time i connect to
>   Azure VPN it creates entries in credentials manager with *session
>   which has no username and thus it tries to use this.

Correct! And the solution is quite easy. Use the information found in the pbk file to create a new VPN connection manually. I've encountered same issue before and the manually created VPN connection works for me.